# Insert/Update php my sql

Tags: php, mysql

**Tengo un archivo `PHP` en el cual hago una consulta. Para realizar un `INSERT` se debe cumplir la condición de que al día de hoy no existan datos con la fecha actual y con la zona en cuestión. Pero, en caso de que exista algún registro con la fecha de hoy y la zona, se hace un `UPDATE`. Pero, por algún motivo no me estaría saliendo, ya que al ingresar los valores por medio de url, me dice que hace un `UPDATE`. Para ser más específico, tengo siete zonas (Córdoba-Mendoza-Etc), a la hora de de realizar la consulta, pregunto si hay datos con el **ID** de la zona y la fecha actual, sino hay nada cargado, pues hace un **INSERT** en caso contrario hará un `UPDATE`, este es mi archivo `PHP`:

```
<?php
    $servername = 'ip';
    $database = 'db';
    $username = 'user';
    $password = 'pass';
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $valor = $_GET[valor];
    $fkZona = $_GET[fkZona];
    $fechaCargaPrecio = $_GET[fechaCargaPrecio];
    $fkUsuario = $_GET[fkUsuario];
    
    $sqlNull = "SELECT * FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE() IS NOT NULL";
    
    $sqlMax = "SELECT precioMaximo FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    $sqlMin = "SELECT precioMinimo FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    
    //iinsert doble
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO cargaPrecioPapas (precioMinimo, precioMaximo, fkZona, fechaCargaPrecio, fkUsuario) 
                 VALUES ('$valor', '$valor', '$fkZona', '$fechaCargaPrecio', '$fkUsuario');";
    
    //Update precio mínimo             
    $sqlUpdMin = "UPDATE cargaPrecioPapas SET precioMinimo = '$valor' WHERE fkZona = $fkZona AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    
    //Update precio máximo
    $sqlUpdMax = "UPDATE cargaPrecioPapas SET precioMaximo = '$valor' WHERE fkZona = $fkZona AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    
    $resultadoNull = $conn->query($sqlNull);
    $max = $conn->query($sqlMax);
    $min = $conn->query($sqlMin);
    
    if ($resultadoNull->num_rows > 0) {
        
        //para traer el valor max y setearlo
        $rowsMax = mysqli_fetch_array($max);
        $valorMax = $rowsMax[0];
        
        //para traer el valor min y setearlo
        $rowsMin = mysqli_fetch_array($min);
        $valorMin = $rowsMin[0];
        
        if($valor > $valorMax){
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdMax)) {
                echo "Max.";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sqlUpdMax . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }else if($valor < $valorMax && $valor > $valorMin){
            echo "Nada.";
        }else{
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdMin)) {
                echo "Min..";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sqlUpdMin . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
     }else{
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert)) {
            echo "Insert";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sqlInsert . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
 $conn->close();
```

Pero, he estado mandando un valor por url por `GET` para probar y resulta que siempre entra en el `UPTDATE` incluso cuando no hay un registro en esa zona en la fecha actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los registros de mi BD existe lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `INSERT` solo se realizó en aquellas zonas en las cuales el **ID no fuera 1-2-3-5** pero la fecha de esos registros es de ayer por lo que en realidad tendría que hacer el `INSERT`. ¿Alguien me podría decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: cuando haces tu prueba, que valor tiene la variable $valor? y puedes hacer un dump a la variable $resultadoNull

Comment: Pues, le pongo cualquier número entre 100 y 999. Pero, el problema radica en que si yo realizo la consulta siguiente:  `select * from tabla where fkzona = 2 and fechaCargaPrecio = curdate() is not null` me trae el registro de ayer es por ello que hace un update @DarkFrost

Comment: y puedes hacer un dump a la variable $resultadoNull?

Comment: Al final de la consulta tienes: `fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE() IS NOT NULL`, tengo la leve sospecha de que sobra `IS NOT NULL` o falta otro elemento para comparar (mucho menos probable).

Comment: el var_dump($resultadoNull) no muestra nada en el if pero si  lo saco por el else sale lo siguiente: **object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**

Comment: Prueba quitando lo que indica Triby, lo que me causa ruido es que entre al if y tu indiques que no contiene nada $resultadoNull.

Comment: Pero en ese caso debe irse por el else, debes hacer el var_dump antes del if, por que al final para que haga el update se debe cumplir la condición del if

Comment: Pues, al hacer eso lo que sucedió es que ahora no entra por los if para hacer el updaate, lo que hace es ir haciendo inserts constantes. Es decir, quité el is not null y ahora, en vez de updatear los valores del registro lo que hace es insertar un nuevo registro

Comment: Si ejecutas la consulta $sqlNull directo por el cliente mysql que te retorna ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La parte que dice '*fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE() IS NOT NULL*' es la que tiene el problema porque ejecuta dos comparaciones lógicas. La primera es:

```
fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()
```

La cual puede devolver **TRUE** o **FALSE**, según existan o no registros con la fecha actual, y la segunda es el resultado de esa operación comparado a '*IS NOT NULL*', lo cual es siempre verdadero:

```
TRUE IS NOT NULL     /* TRUE
FALSE IS NOT NULL    /* TRUE
```

O sea que el resultaado de la operación '*fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE() IS NOT NULL*' siempre será **TRUE**, y tu consulta se convierte en:

```
$sqlNull = "SELECT * FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND TRUE";
```

Lo restantes es '*fkZona' = '$fkZona*', lo cual siempre tendrá un resultado (a menos que pases una zona no válida) y entonces toda tu consulta siempre devolverá un resultado, entrando siempre en las consultas *UPDATE*.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y por tomarte el tiempo en explicar